# Rack::Cache vs regular Rails Caching

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, rack

I am in the process of trying to understand caching options in Rails (and caching in general).

I am having a hard time wrapping my brain around the difference between an option like Rack::Cache and the built-in caching options (page, action, fragment). Would I use one OR the other? Or are they for different things?

Thanks for any wisdom on the topic!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Rack::Cache` will be working on the level of HTTP traffic.

This makes `Rack::Cache` a suitable replacement for the rails page-level caching (though I do not know if it is a *good idea* to do so) -- but it can't be used as a replacement for fragment caching.

You'll definitely want the fragment caching if it takes a lot of processing time / power to create your fragments *and* your fragments are re-used several times before they are invalidated. (The usual caching tradeoff.) I could easily image website designs that are useless without fragment caching and the alternative where fragment caching is unnecessary overhead. Most websites will fall somewhere in the middle.

So if you wish to use `Rack::Cache`, I'm sure it is very useful for what it can do, but it can't replace fragment caching.

Comment: Rack::Cache is essentially an easy-to-deploy reverse-proxy that is bolted onto your app. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_proxy

Answer (score 3):

From: http://rtomayko.github.com/rack-cache/faq

> #### Q: Why Rack::Cache? Why not use Rails/Merb/FrameworkX’s caching
>   system?
>
> Rack::Cache takes a standards-based approach to caching that provides
>   some benefits over framework-integrated systems. It uses standard HTTP
>   headers (Expires, Cache-Control, Etag, Last-Modified, etc.) to
>   determine what/when to cache. Designing applications to support these
>   standard HTTP mechanisms gives the benefit of being able to switch to
>   a different HTTP cache implementation in the future.
>
> In addition, using a standards-based approach to caching creates a
>   clear separation between application and caching logic. The
>   application need only specify a basic set of information about the
>   response and all decisions regarding how and when to cache is moved
>   into the caching layer.

So you can Rails caching, or Rack::Cache, or both if you want. They just work differently. Use whatever makes sense for you application.

Your decision could be based on wanting to use HTTP standard headers (like the FAQ quote above shows), or based on just what syntax you like, or etc... The decision depends on the specifics of the app and your personal tastes.